# How can I select records on the basis of their timings between specific times in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this sample data and part of the query [See the Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b53e9/2). It shows the segment start time and end time. The task is get the sum of all the time segments between 6am to 10pm in seconds. I have filter it on the day but how can I restrict between 6am and 10 pm is difficult for me (May be another condition in the Case statement). The second difficulty is how to get part of a segment when its start time is  5am and endtime is 7am then I want to display 3600 seconds for the part which lies between 6am to 10pm. Similarly if a segment starts at 9pm and finished at 5am then I want to get 3600 seconds i.e. the part before 10pm.

```
Select 
  userid,
  CASE
    WHEN DateDiff(day, starttime, endtime) = 0 THEN datediff(second, starttime, endtime) 
  END As TotalSecondsFromSixAMToTenPM      
FROM
  Test
```

Here is the expected result, Note the first and second last value is obtained by taking these values

```
Select datediff(second,  '2015-01-14 06:00:00.000', '2015-01-14 09:25:54.000')
Select datediff(second, '2015-01-14 21:30:14.000', '2015-01-14 22:00:00.000')


╔════════╦══════════════════════════════╗
║ userid ║ TotalSecondsFromSixAMToTenPM ║
╠════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║ abc    ║ 12354                        ║
║ abc    ║ 3600                         ║
║ abc    ║ 15150                        ║
║ abc    ║ 14684                        ║
║ abc    ║ 1786                         ║
║ abc    ║ NULL                         ║
╚════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH splittedDates AS 
(
    SELECT
        userid,
        CAST(StartTime as date) 'StartDate',
        CAST(EndTime as date) 'EndDate',
        CAST(StartTime as time) 'stime',
        CAST(EndTime as time) 'etime',
        StartTime,
        EndTime
    FROM Test
), correctedTimes AS (
    SELECT userid,
    CASE WHEN StartDate=EndDate AND stime<etime AND stime<'10pm' THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN stime>='6am' THEN StartTime
            ELSE cast(StartDate as datetime) + cast('6am' as datetime)
        END
    END 'correctedStartTime',
    CASE WHEN StartDate=EndDate AND stime<etime AND etime>'6am' THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN etime<='10pm' THEN EndTime
            ELSE cast(StartDate as datetime) + cast('10pm' as datetime)
        END
    END 'correctedEndTime'
    FROM splittedDates
)
SELECT 
  userid,
  datediff(second, correctedStartTime, correctedEndTime) TotalSecondsFromSixAMToTenPM
FROM correctedTimes
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10c2d/6/0)

result:

```
| userid | TotalSecondsFromSixAMToTenPM |
|--------|------------------------------|
|    abc |                        12354 |
|    abc |                         3600 |
|    abc |                        15150 |
|    abc |                        14684 |
|    abc |                         1786 |
|    abc |                       (null) |
```

**EDIT**

I added conditions `stime<'10pm'` and `etime>'6am'` to resolve the issue from comments

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will it work for multiple users and extract times between 6 am and 10 pm for multiple days. I will try it tomorrow morning but any reply.

Comment: Because i ran it in the fiddle and it is generating the expected output.  I have a doubt about its working for multiple days and multiple users.

Comment: @Dmitry, There is a small bug, i.e. if the time starts after 10pm then it keeps the end time 10pm, so it is keeping the starttime as 10:15pm and endtime as 10pm which results in negative time. any idea?

Comment: Here is what I mean http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10c2d/3. I would like to see 0 for segments which falls in 10pm to 6am. Do we need another case statement?

Comment: @Asbat, I edited the query and replaced the fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MS SQL in front of me so I can't test this, but how about something like the following?

```
Select 
  userid,
  CASE
    WHEN DateDiff(day, starttime, endtime) = 0 and starttime>=6am and endTime<=10am

    THEN datediff(second, starttime, endtime) 
  END As TotalSecondsFromSixAMToTenPM      
FROM
  Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
  (
    Userid nvarchar(20),
    FirstDay date,
    LastDay date,
    StartTime time,
    EndTime time
    )

    INSERT INTO TEST(Userid, FirstDay, LastDay, StartTime, EndTime)
    VALUES (  N'abc', '20150113', '20150924', '20150114 05:30:00', '20150114 09:25:54'),
           (  N'abc', '20150113', '20150924', '20150114 09:25:54', '20150114 10:25:54'),
           (  N'abc', '20150113', '20150924', '20150114 13:13:00', '20150114 17:25:30'),
           (  N'abc', '20150113', '20150924', '20150114 17:25:30', '20150114 21:30:14'),
           (  N'abc', '20150113', '20150924', '20150114 21:30:14', '20150114 23:25:54'),
           (  N'abc', '20150113', '20150924', '20150114 23:25:54', '20150115 07:40:10')
```

Query:

```
Select *
    , T1 = Case When DATEDIFF(DAY, FirstDay, LastDay) > 1 Then (DATEDIFF(DAY, FirstDay, LastDay)-1)*(22-6)*60*60 Else 0 End
    , DATEDIFF(SECOND, Case When StartTime < '06:00:00' then '06:00:00' When StartTime < '22:00:00' then StartTime end
        , Case When FirstDay = LastDay Then 
            Case When EndTime > '22:00:00' Then '22:00:00' Else EndTime End
            Else '22:00:00' end
    )
    , T3 = Case When FirstDay <> LastDay Then
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, '06:00:00', Case When EndTime > '22:00:00' Then '22:00:00'
            When EndTime > '06:00:00' Then EndTime
            End)
    Else 0 End
From test
```

- T1 is the number of seconds for full days
- T2 is the number of seconds for the first day
- T3 is the number of seconds for the last day

Your total is T1+T2+T3

Output:

```
Userid  FirstDay    LastDay     StartTime         EndTime           T1          T2      T3
abc     2015-01-13  2015-09-24  05:30:00.0000000  09:25:54.0000000  14572800    57600   12354
abc     2015-01-13  2015-09-24  09:25:54.0000000  10:25:54.0000000  14572800    45246   15954
abc     2015-01-13  2015-09-24  13:13:00.0000000  17:25:30.0000000  14572800    31620   41130
abc     2015-01-13  2015-09-24  17:25:30.0000000  21:30:14.0000000  14572800    16470   55814
abc     2015-01-13  2015-09-24  21:30:14.0000000  23:25:54.0000000  14572800    1786    57600
abc     2015-01-13  2015-09-24  23:25:54.0000000  07:40:10.0000000  14572800    NULL    6010
```

If you don't want seconds accross several day, which is not clear from your question and your samples, this query is enough:

```
Select *
    , DATEDIFF(Second, Case When Cast(StartTime as time) < '06:00:00' then '06:00:00' 
                        When Cast(StartTime as time) < '22:00:00' then Cast(StartTime as time) end
        , Case When Cast(EndTime as time) > '22:00:00' then '22:00:00' 
            When Cast(EndTime as time) > '06:00:00' then Cast(EndTime as time) end
    )
From test
```

Output:

```
abc 12354
abc 3600
abc 15150
abc 14684
abc 1786
abc NULL
```

Comment: Why T3 is not equal with expected results?

Comment: You don't want to count second across multiple days?

Comment: I do want to count seconds for multiple days between 6am to 10pm. It is a sample table.